# Image attachment doesn't appear in notification email

Tags: webforms

I have an image upload field where a user can attach an image. (This is for the *Parts and Service* page for a product site.)

On the notification email to the Service Department, the only way the image is accessible is if I display a link to the image, which appears as a broken thumbnail no matter what I do. Attempting to display the image just results in a broken thumbnail, with no link.

Insofar as they can access the image via the link, it's not the end of the world. But the email looks "broken" - I should be able to display a thumbnail, at least.

Do you have any idea?

I am using Drupal 9.4.8 and Webform 6.1.3; the site runs on PHP 8.0.

Comment: You have a link to the image. You put `<img src="{{ link_to_the_image_token }}" />` in the mail body.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, leymannx - much appreciated! It's not apparent to me what the correct token is nor where it would go, but I've since found that I may be able to attach the image if I use the SMTP module. (Settings > Emails / Handlers > Edit > Attachments.) 

So I'm going to try that first as soon as I can get the correct credentials from the company's IT department. They're using the nightmare of Office365, so that's yet another adventure.

One way or the other, I'll figure it out - thanks mucho!